# PHP Array re-arrange to Multi Dimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array structure like this and wanted to Re-arrange it to the one below. Any suggestions for a faster/simple fix? I already did the addition of the dates. Thanks! :)

**Input:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 255
            [display_name] => Mark
            [company_name] => Company_A
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 150
            [display_name] => Paul
            [company_name] => Company_A
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 25
            [display_name] => Hulk
            [company_name] => Company_B
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 50
            [display_name] => Bob
            [company_name] => Company_B
        )
)
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Company_A] => Array
        (
            [company_total_hours] => 20h 45m
            [employees] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 255
                            [display_name] => Mark
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 150
                            [display_name] => Paul
                        )
                )
        )
    [Company_B] => Array
        (
            [company_total_hours] => 7h 30m
            [employees] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 25
                            [display_name] => Hulk
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 50
                            [display_name] => Bob
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**My Attempts:**

```
<?php
$company_names = array();
foreach ($records as $k => $v) {
    $company_names[] = $v->company_name;
}
$company_names = array_unique($company_names);

// hard coded testing
if (count($company_names) > 0) {
    foreach($company_names as $k2 => $v2) {
        $final_array[$v2]['company_total_hours'] = rand(1, 20);

        $final_array[$v2]['employees'] = array(
            array('user_id' => '255', 'display_name' => 'Mark'),
            array('user_id' => '150', 'display_name' => 'Paul')
        );
    }
}

// on-going testing right now here....
```

Comment: Please post your attempts. What you have tried and where did you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you derive your hours from so I left that out.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($vals as $keys => $arrays) {
        if(!isset($new[$arrays['company_name']]))
            $i = 0;
        $new[$arrays['company_name']]['employees'][$i]['display_name']  =   $arrays['display_name'];
        $new[$arrays['company_name']]['employees'][$i]['user_id']       =   $arrays['user_id'];
        $i++;
    }
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [Company_A] => Array
        (
            [employees] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [display_name] => Mark
                            [user_id] => 255
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [display_name] => Paul
                            [user_id] => 150
                        )

                )

        )

    [Company_B] => Array
        (
            [employees] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [display_name] => Hulk
                            [user_id] => 25
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [display_name] => Bob
                            [user_id] => 50
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly. Also other answers worked as well. I just added the "company_total_hours" key you forgot. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $v)
{
   if(!$arr2[$v['company_name']]['employees'])
      $arr2[$v['company_name']]['employees'] = array();
   if(!$arr2[$v['company_name']]['company_total_hours'])
      $arr2[$v['company_name']]['company_total_hours'] = '2h';//addional value
   $arr2[$v['company_name']]['employees'][] = array('user_id'=>$v['user_id'],
      'display_name'=>$v['display_name']
   );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function which does the same thing as the answer given by @Rasclatt.

```
function groupByKeyValue($array, $oldKeyName, $newKeyName){
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(isset($newArray[$value[$oldKeyName]][$newKeyName])){
            $newArray[$value[$oldKeyName]][$newKeyName][] = array('user_id'=> $value['user_id'], 'display_name' => $value['display_name']);
        }else{
            $newArray[$value[$oldKeyName]] = array($newKeyName => array(array('user_id'=> $value['user_id'], 'display_name' => $value['display_name'])));
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
//usage
$newArray = groupByKeyValue($array, 'company_name', 'employees');
```

You can add a third parameter to send the keys for the array values which needs to be used in the new array for 'employees'. Please check this link for the working of the function http://goo.gl/I6Of5y